# Error building OpenSSL 1.0.1c with MSVC 2010

Tags: windows, visual-c++, openssl, visual-studio-2010

I have successfully configured OpenSSL for building, but when I run `nmake` I get this:

```
c:\Development\Qt\5\OpenSSL>nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak test

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl /Fotmp32dll\md4test.obj -Iinc32 -Itmp32dll /MD /Ox /O2 /Ob2 -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32
-W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
-DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK -I. -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE
-DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE /Zi /Fdtmp32dll/app -c .\crypto\md4\md4test.c

.\crypto\md4\md4test.c : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database 'c:\development\qt\5\openssl\tmp32dll\app.pdb'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Advices appreciated.

Comment: Try using /Z7 instead of /Zi.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when some other application is trying access the file at the same time. For me, it was Dropbox. So, I had to disable the sync.

Another program which accesses the PDB files during compilation is mspdbsrv.exe. This program is started automatically by the build process. Kill it, and remove all the files in tmp32dll folder. It may have been left over from the previous build attempts.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error when I accidentally built with "ms\nt.mak", but then tried to test with "ms\ntdll.mak".   Make sure you build and test with the same make file.